# Dynamic source attribute update not working in chromium

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I have a script of which the part relevant to the question is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageOnClick() {
        var image = $("#image_id");
        $(image).attr("src", "ajax-loader.gif");
        $.ajax({
            // do staffs
            complete: function () {
                $(image).attr("src", "default.gif");   // ***     
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and IE-8. However, in GoogleChrom(21.0.1180.83) the loading image is shown and then the `complete` is invoked, the source of image is changed, but not displayed. I have checked the image element's `src` attribute is changed to `default.gif` as expected but space of image is left blank.

**Is this a common problem with a trivial solution?** Or I have to rechech the large `imageOnClick` function?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/TYdQ6/1/) fiddle works for me in Chrome 21.0.1180.79.

I'm not sure why you are experiencing problems, but the extra selection of the image object is at least superfluous. `var image = $("#image_id");` gives a jQuery object (or an array of them). Doing `$(image)` later will give you the exact same object.

And you might also want to read up on [prop() vs. attr()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I mentioned that its only a part of a large function. the image object is use somewhere else. But yes, `$(image)` can be replaced with `image`.

Comment: In that case, all I can think of is that you are modifying the `image` object by mistake in between the two `attr()` calls.

Comment: No, I have tried `$("#image_id").attr("src", "default.gif");`. Does not work either. Also, your fiddler works fine for me too.   BTW, my question was not actually what you have answered. Please reread the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Then, no. It is not a common problem. Is your work available at a public server so I could see it in action? I might be able to help you if I could debug it properly.

Comment: Per, Actually the problem is in a completely different place than I thought. My question does not say anything about that part and I have solved it. I think I should close/delete the question. +1 for your effort. I cannot accept the answer because the question is improper and others can be misguided.